# Instance Labels appear rather than Instance name in message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alert, monitoring

I recently deployed several GCP alerts and the message that sent out via email sometimes contains the instance name and other times just the VM Instance labels and no instance name after the project ID.  Could you explain the reason behind the variation in the alert message and why Cloud Monitoring sometimes includes VM Instance labels rather than instance name?   Also, I have seen several issues in StackOverflow indicating that GCP Monitoring alert messages cannot be altered.  Is this still the case?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Bill! I hope you are doing amazing. Can you add more information about your question; Like when you say "I recently deployed several GCP alerts", what type of alerts are you talking about? Are they uptime checks? Log based metrics? All the information you can add can help the community to better address all your concerns.

Comment: Hi Armando, These are Cloud Monitoring alerts for High CPU that were originally created in metrics explorer.  For example, CPU utilization for terra-proj-xxxx projectname with system labels {state=ACTIVE} is above the threshold of 0.85 with a value of 1.030.   appears in most message alaerts.  However in some the project name is substituted for VM Instance labels followed by {proj_id=xxx, mig, instance_id=xxx}.  How do you get consistency in the alert messages?  thanks

Comment: Ok a little more information on what is going on.  This issue appears to be a bug.  I have tried to recreate the problem several times by putting labels on instances and it does not matter.  On some instances the message is displayed properly (ie. the project name and instance name appear) and on a different machine the instance name is left off and instance labels only appear.  It is my understanding that the same alert message should appear every time and this behavior cannot be altered by the user.  Look forward to hearing some additional comments on this issue.  Thanks

Comment: when setting up the target to get the metrics, there's a " Query Editor" button that shows your metrics settings in code format, would you mind to share that query to review it? (of course omit or delete your project ID and that sensible stuff). it maybe related to a label filter that was provided with no value or empty.

Comment: Hi Jaime, We are going to try updating the Terraform to include the following in the message generation text: "VM Instance - Memory utilization for used by label.instance_name [MEAN]".   This was the suggested title in the query editor. Previously I had written out a message.  As long as the project and the host project are the same there is not a problem.  But once a project becomes a guest project for monitoring purposes the message does not include the project name.  Will let you know if the change works.  Thanks